# Default desktop theme still boots, after being deleted

Tags: ubuntu, theme

Ubuntu 20.04 still boots into the default desktop theme, on Budgie and Gnome.

This is after I deleted/moved **all** the desktop environment themes:

`sudo mv /usr/share/themes /usr/share/themes_backup`

`rm -Rfv $HOME/.themes`

`rm -Rfv $HOME/.local/share/themes`

How is this possible?

---

NB. Also asked under question here:
https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/cannot-change-themes-after-hard-reset/5066/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If by “default theme” you mean “the default theme for GTK applications
> and GNOME Shell”, then it’s expected: the default themes in both cases
> is embedded into GTK and GNOME Shell, respectively, as without a
> default theme both applications and the shell would be utterly broken.
>
> I guess the actual question is: what is it that you’re trying to
> achieve.
>
> ebassi, GNOME Team

Answer quoted from https://discourse.gnome.org/t/is-the-default-desktop-theme-backed-up-outside-usr-share-themes/6877